# What all should Laravel's routes.php have?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm coming from CodeIgniter and the routes.php file meant only routing for me (with not much logic really). However the way Laravel's routes seems to be in place; kinda gives an image that adding some logic and functionality in routes directly isn't bad (instead of going to the Controller or Model).

I have a simple Logout functionality setup in the routes.php this way

```
/*
 * Route and action for logout
 */
Route::get('logout', function()
{
    Session::flush();                                // Remove session data
    return Redirect::route('home');                  // Redirect to home
});
```

Is it fine? I'm never going to a controller/model since..

Also is it okay to call more than one function in the route itself?
Like:

```
/*
 * Route for home
 */
Route::get('/', array('as' => 'home', function()
{
     $var_1 = SomeModel1::function1();             
     $var_2 = SomeModel2::function1($var1);         

     return View::make('home')->with('var', $var_2);

}));
```

Is it okay whatever I'm doing above (contacting the models directly from the routes), or should it be done in a better way?

Comment: Yes, you can embed any logic you wish. This is indeed very handy, when your project is small. If your project becomes bigger however, it's easier to use controllers for logic, as it keeps things a little more separated and abstracted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write all of your system only from `app/routes.php`, but in medium and big sized project(s), to make them in order, you would better prefer using controllers for each section.

Example:

Add this line in `app/routes.php`:

```
Route::get('logout',array('as'=>'logout','uses'=>'AuthController@getLogout'));
```

And the `app/controllers/AuthController.php`:

```
<?php

class AuthController extends BaseController {

    public function getLogout() {
        Session::flush(); // Remove session data
        return Redirect::route('home');
    }
}
```

This way, I made a resource named `logout`, which uses `app/controllers/AuthController.php` 's `getLogout()` method.

Comment: Thanks! What do you think about the second part of my question?

Comment: @JohnSmith by two functions, did you mean model methods? If so, of course, they are okay.

Comment: Yes, I was wondering should I only call one method and let that method only do everything in the controller.

Comment: @JohnSmith It's a good practice to do anything database related or similar on models. In my opinion, controllers should hold just the logic of the application and process all the resources (that has been provided from model, parameters, post etc.) and redirection the user.